# Converting Date column to proper sas dates and creating Year/month columns, from this date 11FEB13:22:59:00 creating year column

Tags: sas

I have a Date column, Type - Numeric, Format - DATETIME., Informat - ANYDTDTM40,

data looks like this:

```
Date
11FEB13:22:59:00
29NOV13:18:03:00
```

Out of this date column i need to create year and month columns.

However when i try:

```
DATA Final;
Set Final;
Year = Year(Date);
Run;
```

I receive null values in the year column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presume `date` variable contains DateTime values:

```
year_int = YEAR(DATEPART(date));
```

SAS Date and DateTime values are numerics with different interpretations.  A Date value is number of days from epoch and DateTime is number of seconds.

There are different functions for extracting different aspects of theses values:

DateTime examples

- `YearPart(<datetime-value>)`
- `TimePart(<datetime-value>)`
- `DateTime()` - current system datetime

Date examples

- `Year(date-value)`
- `Month(<date-value>)`
- `Day(<date-value>)`

One of the best organized references for these classes of functions is found in the [ETS documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=etsug&docsetTarget=etsug_intervals_sect014.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en) which documents a whopping 36 different functions.

The [DS2 version of this documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=ds2pg&docsetTarget=n09slu1tsftvlqn14un8v7cbufig.htm&docsetVersion=3.1&locale=en) is pretty clean too.

Base SAS documentation lists the same Date and Time functions in page ["SAS Functions and CALL Routines by Category"](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n01f5qrjoh9h4hn1olbdpb5pr2td.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

Answer (score 0):

Try using format!

```
 set Final;
format date date9.;
Run;
DATA Final;
Set Final;
Year = year(date);
Run;
```

Comment: Still receiving blanks, i believe formatting the date will not change the actual values, and when i use Year() function i receive nulls.

Comment: data final2;
set FINAL;
format date date9.;
Run;  i tried this, it throws error: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.